# Subquery only if it contains rows

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have a subquery built into a query. But I want that to ONLY occur if the subquery table (shop_stock) actually has rows in it.

```
SELECT id
FROM item
WHERE restocks_at = ?
AND rarity > ?
AND rarity < ?
AND price > 0
AND amount < (SELECT COUNT(id)
   FROM shop_stock
   WHERE item_id = item.id
   AND shop_id = ?)
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```

I want the amount column in the item table to only be less than the rows in the table (shop_stock) with that item ID IF it actually contains rows at all. Because since it has no rows to begin with, it's going to not even pull anything from the query at all.
But I'm looping through a loop of how many items I want to insert and in the very beginning, it's going to have NOTHING in that table (shop_stock).

If it never inserts that ID into that table, this query will never run. So I'm confused. I want to basically count the item ID and how much it occurs in the subquery if it is even in the table at all.

SO OVERALL, each item has an amount (2-30) which means ITEM ID 21 might have an amount of 5 MEANING that I only want the MAX of 5 items to restock of that item. So I'm trying to not make two queries where I have to select an item and then check if it's already in the shop_stock table 5 times and if it isn't, insert the item into the shop_stock.

Comment: Could you clarify this question a bit more please? Try replacing all of the "that table" parts with the table names that you are talking about. Better still; for every column that you mention use the form <tableName>.<columnName> e.g. item.amount

Answer (score 0):

Ok wow honestly.. the sign was just placed the wrong way. IF amount > what's already in the subquery table, then insert.. Not less than... :/ Sorry..

```
SELECT id
FROM item
WHERE restocks_at = 1
AND rarity > 5
AND rarity < 60
AND price > 0
AND amount > (SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM shop_stock
    WHERE item_id = item.id
    AND shop_id = 1)
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1
```